# Is it wrong to use wildcard LIKE % on an integer/double bind type

Tags: php, sql, prepared-statement

I'm trying to create a prepared statement for a search page. I want it to ignore if the user didn't specify the price amount to search so I did it this way:

```
if ($_POST["price"] == ""){
 $ItemPrice = "item_price LIKE ?";
}
else
{
 $ItemPrice = "item_price = ?";
}
```

`$ItemPrice` will be added to the statement. If `$_POST["price"]` is empty (The user didn't specify it) then I would assign `%` to the ? so it becomes `item_price LIKE %`. It doesn't seem to work. The bind type for this is a `Double`. Please help confirm if this is true but does using wildcard on a double or integer type fails the query?

I needed to code it this way so if the user didn't specify the price to search then all results regardless of price amount will be displayed.

EDIT: Looks like no answer for this so I'll just share what I did. I didn't use the LIKE statement for double or integer type fields that I will be using in a bind/param. It seem to work now. I think the mistake was trying to use `"item_price LIKE ?"` when `?` will be declared as double/integer in bind_param statement

Comment: paste full block of code. nothing wrong in your code here.

Comment: If you want to ignore the blank price input. You can simply use `if( empty($_POST["price"]) ) exit;` then it's done.

Comment: It seems as if you want to ignore the Price filter if value is not specified by User. Then, simply remove that condition from search query. This way, you will get what you want.

Comment: Hi guys, I am using a prepared statement where the parameters are static not dynamic. The ? here is included in the bind_param statement, wouldn't it cause an error if there are less ? marks in the statements compared to the parameters included in the bind_param statement?